# Sub-classing custom classes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’ve been a procedural programmer for a long time and most of my iOS code is written with lots of if statements instead of sub-classing. I think I finally understand how to write object oriented code but I have a few questions.

I have a class, ScoringToolbar.m that is used in all of my games. It creates buttons for the bottom of the screen. Which buttons are created vary depending on the game and the options in the game. Here’s a typical screen.

[image: Scoring Toolbar]

Right now it is a long series of if statements. In addition to being hard to read, it’s definitely not proper object oriented programming. What I’d like to do is convert the class into a superclass and add a subclass for each game. My first question is: Is there a convention for naming the superclass?

Also, I’d like to keep the ScoringToolbar.m name for each of my sub-classes. If I create one sub-class for each of my apps (or group of similar apps) I can move the code from the if statements into it. Then each app would call its own subclass and create the buttons it needs. If I do that I won’t have to change any of the calling code. However, if I have lots of .m files with the same name, what do I do with the .h files. Do I have just one and make sure it works with all of the .m's. Or is there a way to tell Xcode to use a specific .h file in an app?

Or is this the wrong approach altogether?

Comment: If the parent class is essentially abstract (i.e. it won't work unless subclassed), then I would call it ScoringToolbarBase.

Comment: I just looked up the definition of abstract classes. I don’t think it will be an abstract class since it will have methods to create the buttons. But I think your naming convention will work.

Comment: Note that objective-c doesn't support true abstract classes. They are typically faked by giving the base class empty implementations for key methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure subclassing is your best option. Your question about multiple .m files with the same name suggests this approach might get confusing. You might want to think of your ScoringToolbar as a control that your apps configure for their needs. In this way it wouldn't be much different than a UIButton. Each app would be responsible for creating an instance of the ScoringToolbar and setting it up to suit. It could do this in a method in an existing class or in a helper class. The ScoringToolbar takes care of rendering the UI (icons, colors) while the calling app indicates what options it needs (up/down votes, number correct/incorrect, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I think subclassing is not a good option for you problem. You will end up with code which is hard to maintain and modify when your apps or no of apps grow big.

Have a look at some design patterns, if I got your problem correctly, builder pattern would be one of the options.

Or you can create configuration file for each game. For example you can have an array of dictionaries in a plist. Each dictionary will represent a UI element in the toolbar. For example you can store the image name, order, selector, position(?) and etc in the plist. When loading the application you can create the toolbar elements at run time using the dictionary options.

These are just a starting point but based on your requirements and extendability of your apps you can find better solutions.